# Issue with Async.Sequential, in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have the following:

```
do!
    [
        [
            TradesDatabase.deleteTradesAsync    credentials time (time.Add oneDay)
            TradesDatabase.insertTradesAsync    credentials trades
        ] |> Async.Sequential
        
        [
            KVWAPDatabase.deleteKVWAPAsync      credentials time (time.Add oneDay)
            KVWAPDatabase.insertKVWAPAsync      credentials output.KVWAP
        ] |> Async.Sequential
        
        [
            CandlesDatabase.deleteCandlesAsync  credentials time (time.Add oneDay)
            CandlesDatabase.insertCandlesAsync  credentials output.Candles
        ] |> Async.Sequential
    ]
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.Ignore
```

The inner code is probably not very useful, these are async db calls.

So for 3 data types I want to process in parallel, I want to do a sequential delete following by an insert.

But the debug's printout is:

```
delete kvwap              <- called by deleteKVWAPAsync
inserting kvwap           <- called by insertKVWAPAsync
done deleting kvwap       <- called by deleteKVWAPAsync
```

so this block:

```
[
    KVWAPDatabase.deleteKVWAPAsync      credentials time (time.Add oneDay)
    KVWAPDatabase.insertKVWAPAsync      credentials output.KVWAP
] |> Async.Sequential
```

was supposed to be executed in order, but it's not.

What am I missing regarding Async.Sequential?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, even if I put a long `Async.Sleep` in the `delete` step. I suspect that maybe you've accidentally copy/pasted the `kvwap` debug output into one of the other parallel branches (either Trades or Candles) without changing the output text?

Comment: It's separate pieces of code and the DB complains about it as well, so the delete is not done in time. When I do the deletes with let!/and!/and! and then the inserts with let!/and!/and! it works properly though. Thanks for looking into it, I'll keep investigating!

Comment: Why don't you use an `async` CE and FusionTasks NuGet and call your async code inside the CE?

Comment: @Andrii if something can run with the base libs, it's better than adding anther package

Comment: If something is already implemented is better to reuse it than invent the wheel 

Comment: But if you prefer to write `Async.AwaitTask` everywhere that is up to you 

Comment: @Andrii, but the Async.AwaitTask generally come from the C# libs, I don't have much of that

Comment: Yes, it does. In that case `async { }` is even more right for you!

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced a similar issue.

It may be the case that your database functions are being run as "hot" tasks. For example, if I remember correctly the following code starts the computation immediately, even though it is returning an `Async<int>`:

```ml
  type DbContext =
   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection * Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction

  let doQuery ((connection, transaction) : DbContext) query =
      (connection.ExecuteAsync(query, transaction))
      |> Async.AwaitTask
```

While this code does not:

```ml
  let doQuery2 ((connection, transaction) : DbContext) query =
    async {
      return! 
        (connection.ExecuteAsync(query, transaction))
        |> Async.AwaitTask
    }
```